# powerbuilder 2022 graphmode SetSeriesStyle doesn't work

Tags: graph, powerbuilder

I want to create a graph in Powerbuilder 2022 using lines. Now I want to change to change some properties of the lines using SetSeriesStyle. In powerbuilder 2021 it works perfect. I am using an event graphcreate with the id pbm_dwngraphcreate. In this event I use the SetSeriesStyle mode, eg:
dw_1.SetSeriesStyle("gr_1", ls_iwtp, LineColor!, RGB(0, 0, 0))
But nothing happens. Only the color of the line in the legend changed. The color of the line in the graph doesn't changed. So what did I wrong. As I said: In PB 2021 it works perfekt.

I use the code as in Powerbuilder 2021 and I expect that the SetSeriesStyle mode works